# How can I make the onClick attribute locate local files

Tags: javascript, html, css, download, mp3

I would like to make the onClick attribute locate local files. My code is this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:downloadResource('/forsongstab/tracks/Villagers of Ioannina City - Age of Aquarius - 01 Welcome.mp3')"><img class="dli" src="../images/downloadicon.jpeg">01. Welcome</a><br>
```

and my script for the onClick attribute:

```
    function downloadBlob(blob, filename) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = blob;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    }
    function downloadResource(url) {
      filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
      fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
      })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadBlob(blobUrl, filename);
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
```

The problem that I have is that when I try to click the download button basically.

If anyone can find a way to fix please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Javascript alone cannot read your local files, which is normal. Imagine if just by opening my website I could access all your files from your hard drive. In order to access this file it must be at least at the same level as your `index.html`.

Comment: So basically you are you telling me that I should move all the mp3 files into the same level as my index.html?

Comment: At least it has to be at the same level but it can also be deeper in your structure.